# How to make ByteBuddy created sub-interface inherit type annotations?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I have this pseudo-test to create a sub-interface and I want to copy annotations from interface S but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import net.bytebuddy.ByteBuddy;
import net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.attribute.MethodAttributeAppender;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.attribute.TypeAttributeAppender;
import net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers;

import org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.annotations.EagerLoad;
import org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.annotations.NotLazy;

public class InheritedMethodTest {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        Method im = I.class.getMethod("list");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(I.class.getAnnotations()));
        System.out.println(im.getDeclaringClass());
        System.out.println(im.getGenericReturnType());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(im.getAnnotations()));
        System.out.println();

        Method sm = S.class.getMethod("list");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(S.class.getAnnotations()));
        System.out.println(sm.getDeclaringClass());
        System.out.println(sm.getGenericReturnType());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sm.getAnnotations()));
        System.out.println();

        Class<? extends Object> f = new ByteBuddy()
                .makeInterface(S.class)
                .attribute(TypeAttributeAppender.ForInstrumentedType.INSTANCE)
                .method(ElementMatchers.not(ElementMatchers
                        .isDeclaredBy(Object.class)))
                .withoutCode()
                .attribute(
                        MethodAttributeAppender.ForInstrumentedMethod.INCLUDING_RECEIVER)
                .make()
                .load(InheritedMethodTest.class.getClassLoader(),
                        ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION).getLoaded();

        Method fm = f.getMethod("list");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(f.getAnnotations()));
        System.out.println(fm.getDeclaringClass());
        System.out.println(fm.getGenericReturnType());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fm.getAnnotations()));

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(f.getInterfaces()));
    }

    public static interface I<A> {
        @NotLazy
        List<A> list();
    }

    @EagerLoad
    public static interface S extends I<String> {
    }

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Or what exactly is wrong.

Comment: This line `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(f.getAnnotations()));`
should return list of one annotation: @EagerLoad, and it doesn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the

```
attribute(TypeAttributeAppender.ForInstrumentedType.INSTANCE)
```

command by

```
annotateType(S.class.getDeclaredAnnotations())
```

The attribute appender only applies the annotations that are directly declared by the instrumented type. In case of creating an interface with potentially mutliple super-interfaces, copying annotations is not possible as this can cause conflicts if multiple interfaces declare the same annotations. Please refer to the documentation of `TypeAttributeAppender.ForInstrumentedType` for a detail description of the attribute appender.